# Ruby - Validate and update URL

Tags: ruby

I've been trying to modify this method from redirecting and returning the contents of the url to returning new valid url instead.

After reading up on the Net::HTTP object, I'm still not sure how exactly the get_response method works. Is this what's downloading the page? is there another method I could call that would just ping the url instead of downloading it?

```
require 'net/http'

def validate(url)
    uri = URI.parse(url)
    response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)

    case response
    when Net::HTTPSuccess
        return response
    when Net::HTTPRedirection
        return validate(response['location'])
    else
        return nill
    end
end


puts validate('http://somesite.com/somedir/mypage.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that `get_response` sends an HTTP GET request to the server, which requests the whole page.

You want to use a HEAD request instead of GET.  This requests the same HTTP response header that a GET request would get, including the status code (200, 404, etc.), but without downloading the whole page.

See the `request_head` and `head` methods of `Net::HTTP`.  For example

```
url = URI.parse('http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/index.html')
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
    http.head(url.path)
}
puts res.class
```

Comment: Thanks, that's working much faster. Just trying to work it in to the original method. How would the `case` work in this situation?

Comment: It's the same as your original code. `res` is an `Net::HTTPResponse` object, just like the `response` in your code.

Comment: I'm getting a `NoMethodError` though when I try to update the object. `validate': undefined method `host' for #<String:0x100311360> (NoMethodError)`

Comment: That means you are calling `host` on a String object instead of a URI object.  Remember to use URI.parse to convert a String to a URI.

Comment: bah! had `uri = URI.parse` then was using `url.host`. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, by 'ping the url', you want to know whether the url request returns an HTTP 200 response?

I haven't looked at the implementation of get_response, but I think it just sends out an HTTP GET request, by the looks of it.

If you want to check for the HTTP 200 response, I guess you could just keep doing get_response until you get HTTPSuccess && HTTPOK.