# Rails - Regex inside a method used for validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a validation that checks the format of a url using regex. I was wondering if it's possible to put the regex inside of a method:

validates_format_of :table_name :with => /^(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([_-.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/ix

How do I put that regex in a method and use it with the validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll work with any class method, or variable/constant that's already defined. But why don't you create a new validator?

```
# config/initializers/my_validators.rb
ActiveRecord::Base.class_eval do
  def self.validates_url_of(attr_name, n, options={})
    validates_format_of attr_name, :with => /^(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([_-.]{1}[a-z0-9]+).[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.)?$/ix
  end
end
```

Then:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_url_of :attribute
end
```

Comment: This one seems to be even better since it allows it to be reusable from multiple models.

Comment: This is a terrible regex for validating URLs.  For a start `[_-.]` is an invalid range, but assuming that was meant to be something like `[-_.]` then the regex matches this non-URL (amongst many others): `http://f_b(xx`

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to tidy up code without creating a custom validation, then use a constant rather than a method to store the regex.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  URL_REGEX = /^(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\_\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/ix

  validates_format_of :table_name :with => URL_REGEX

end
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#creating-custom-validation-methods

Comment: Thanks for reply. I checked out the link but I could not find any examples of putting the regex inside a method then calling it from the validation.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you take a look at [Ruby - Validate and update URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107424/ruby-validate-and-update-url) for a much better validation method than regex.

If you're desperate to use Regex, then take a look at [this writeup from John Gruber](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls) for something much more valuable than the above.